# Is there a maximum amount of queries that MySQL can execute within a single transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have a program that analyzes a set of very large text data on the internet all day every day. Currently I am iterating through this data & storing it. However I recently learned that it is faster and more robust to use `beginTransaction` and `commit` with [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). The structure of this code beforehand was the same, without the `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` statements. **I am wondering if it is possible while using a transaction I am inadvertently endangering my server/program's integrity by introducing a new point of failure: memory hard limit**. Here is some pseudocode that describes what is going on:

```
$database->beginTransaction();
$query = $database->prepare("insert into data_storage (id, data, time) values (?, ?, ?);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataset); $i++)
{
    $etc = get_data_from_curl($dataset[i]["url"]);
    $query->bindParam(1, $etc[0]);
    $query->bindParam(2, $etc[1]);
    $query->bindParam(3, $etc[2]);
    $query->execute();
}
$database->commit();
```

This has resulted in a 15% faster execution of my script on my tests where the size of `$dataset` is around 2000. However, I am not sure if `beginTransaction()` adds any additional memory constraints on my server. I'm using a free amazon server, and the integrity of the server is extremely important to my project.

Sometimes it takes over a day to record all of the new data.
Is it possible that this much new data will cause my program/database to crash because of memory constraints?

Is there a better, faster way to do this? I have heard about stored procedures, and how they improve database functionality, but I am not sure how to apply them in this scenario to make this process faster.

Comment: for th large inserts use LOAD DATA INFILE

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make your database writes faster, do not make them dependent on such terrible slow operations like network lookups.